# R function behaviour depends on where the function is stored, as well as on how the parameters are transferred

Tags: r, regex, encoding, parameter-passing, cyrillic

I noticed a strange behavior of a R function that I had written. The function returns different values, depending on whether the function is stored in the same file as the executed code, depending on the way the parameters are transferred, and depending on the encoding of the parameters.

Example:

```
##Code part 1:
some_function <- function(str, pattern, pattern1 = "УИК №[0-9]+"){
  cat(str_extract(str, pattern), "\n")
  cat(str_extract(str, pattern1), "\n")
  cat(str_extract(str, "УИК №[0-9]+"))
}

##Code part 2:
library(stringr)
some_function("УИК №221", pattern = "УИК №[0-9]+")
```

Now, if "Code part 1" is stored in the same R file as "Code part 2", everything works well and the result is
"УИК №221" 
"УИК №221" 
"УИК №221".
However, if "Code part 1" is stored in another R file, e.g. "functions.R", and I call it in "Code part 2" via "source(functions.R)", then this functions prints 
"УИК №221" 
NA
NA.
Has anybody any idea why this happens?

If no cyrillic letters are used, then it doesn't make a difference in which file the function is stored and how the parameters are transferred.

E.g. with the altered code parts
Code part 1:
some_function <- function(str, pattern, pattern1 = "UIK No[0-9]+"){
  cat(str_extract(str, pattern), "\n")
  cat(str_extract(str, pattern1), "\n")
  cat(str_extract(str, "UIK No[0-9]+"))
}

Code part 2:
library(stringr)
some_function("UIK No221", pattern = "UIK No[0-9]+")

the printed result is in both cases
UIK No221 
UIK No221 
UIK No221 .

Ideas regarding this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you writing these files with different editors? Are they using different encodings? Is this a windows machine?

Comment: Both files are written with R Studio, on Windows, and the encoding should be the same, "windows-1251" (as it was just copy-paste between these codes...).

Comment: However, the original encoding of the data was probably  "windows-1251" (russian) and I saved both R codes in UTF-8 format. Could this be an issue?